# how to import sklearn.impute?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Problem is that I can't import module from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.impute'
```

After reading google search results I tried to install

```
pip install scikit-learn=0.19.1.
```

Then I got

```
"ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'scikit-learn=0.19.1'
= is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?"
```

Instead of = put ==, but no result.

Can anyone explain,please, what does cause the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I am using 0.21.0

Answer (score 2):

Version 0.19 will not help you; until then, `Impute` was part of the `preprocessing` module ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer)), and there was not a `SimpleImputer` class.

`SimpleImputer` became part of the new `sklearn.impute` module only in version 0.20 ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute)), so this (or a newer one) is the version you need; you can upgrade to the latest version 0.21.2 with

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: I am using 0.21.0. Still need to be upgraded?

Comment: @bright it should work with 0.21: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

Answer (score 0):

I have sklearn 0.21.3 installed

All these options work for me:

```
import sklearn.impute
from sklearn import impute
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

Try to reinstall scikit-learn and try again. This must help

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1 : use the following, to know the version :

```
import sklearn 
print (sklearn.__version__)
```

if the version is 0.19.1, then there isn't an issue.

- Step 2 : use the following, to know the version :

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

- To install a new version do :

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```